# Алгоритм процедурной расстановки препятствий на уровне

Tags: алгоритм, unity3d

Пишу процедурное появление препятствий в 3d игре. Есть некий участок с габаритами Xp,Yp и Zp. На нем необходимо разместить N препятствий с разными габаритами Xo, Yo и Zo так, чтобы персонаж с габаритами Xc, Yc и Zc всегда мог пройти между препятствиями или перепрыгнуть (высота прыжка Hc) его.

Для простоты высоту можно опустить и создавать препятствия на плоскости XZ.
Пространство поделено на клетки (можно сравнить с шахматной доской), а габариты объектов (в том числе препятствий) указаны в клетках.

Не могу сформулировать алгоритм расположения препятствий. Может быть, кто-то знает, в какую сторону копать, или сможет дать какой-то совет.
Прошу, подскажите.
[image: Пример вида сверху]

Comment: Может лучше поступить наоборот? Сгенерить маршрут. А всё остальное будет препятствием.

Comment: А какие ограничения на генерацию препятствий вы хотите выставить? Чтобы был маршрут из одной точки в другую или еще что-то такое.

Comment: А вообще, по запросу "генерация стен" гугл выдает кучу статей с хабра. Возможно, там есть что-то подходящее для вашего случая.

Comment: @Sergey Интересное предложение, благодарю, покопаю в этом направлении. Но препятствиями выступают деревья, кусты, камни. И растягивать как попало их не получится, чтобы занимать все ненужное пространство.
Да и придется генерить несколько маршрутов, чтобы у игрока была вариативность.

Comment: @EzikBro Ограничение такое, что препятствия (и их размеры) определены заране. 
Вообще задумка такая, что у препятствий есть некая мнимая величина, означающая сложность, я назвал ее вес. А у участка есть величина, означающая сумму весов препятствий внутри этого участка.
Алгоритм должен подбирать препятствия таким образом, чтобы сумма их весов была наиболее приближена к сумме весов, которую участок может вместить. Таким образом я смогу регулировать сложность.

Comment: А можно немного узнать про суть игры? Чем именно препятствия будут мешать игроку? И приведите пример, как вы бы вручную эти препятствия расставляли: что вам дано, как вы это делаете, какие метрики после расстановки замеряете. А то иначе получаются рассуждения о сферическом коне в вакууме.

Comment: @EzikBro игра - ранер. Игровой персонаж бежит вперед по прямой, но может смещаться в соседние полосы. Всего N полос (на данный момент решили, что 3 полосы).
Также есть противник, он тоже бежит, перепрыгивает препятствия. Его поведение такое, что он никогда не врезается в препятствия.
По ходу передвижения игрока перед ним появляются куски локации, внутри них препятствия.

Comment: @EzikBro На данный момент есть кое-какая реализация расстановки препятствий.
Каждые N клеток по прямой появляется случайное препятствие таким образом, чтобы оно не вылазило за пределы игровой области (для этого у препятствий есть значения габаритов).
После появления препятствия, клетки, на которых оно находится, становятся занятыми, и на них нельзя поставить другое препятствие.

Comment: http://lab18.ipu.ru/projects/conf2009/3/27..htm тут есть нечто похожее на, что мне нужно